# Symfony 4: catch exception

Tags: php, symfony

I am trying to catch errors but it doesn't work, I always see the Symfony Exception page,do you see any errors in my code?
thanks in advance.

```
namespace App\Controller;
use App\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\AcceptHeader;
use Doctrine\ORM\ORMException;
use Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException;


public function index() {
        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $content = $request->getContent();        
        $prod = [];
        $response = null;
        try
        {
            //$product->setPrice($request -> request -> get('price'));
            ....            
        }                  
        catch(\DBALException $e){
            $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
            $response = New Response();
            $response -> setContent($errorMessage);
            $response -> setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            $errorMessage = $e->getMessage();
            $response = New Response();
            $response -> setContent($errorMessage);
            $response -> setStatusCode(Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);

        }

        $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        return $response;             
}
```

and this is the errors
[image]
thanks
Andrea

Comment: What line is actually throwing an exception and what kind of exception exactly?

Comment: it's a parameter that is missing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you are not showing the line that is throwing the exception, it looks like you are not using the correct namespace: The Doctrine `DBALException` is namespaced and `\DBALException` does not exist in Symfony 4.

You probably want:

```
 catch (\Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException $e) {
```

or just:

```
catch (DBALException $e) {
```

if you have a `use \Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException;` statement at the top of your class.

**Edit:** The error you have shown, is not an exception but an error. You should fix this so that it cannot occur, but if you want to catch it, you could do that just like you catch the exceptions:

```
catch (\Error $e) {
```

or:

```
catch (\TypeError $e) {
```

Comment: I just wanted to catch, it  worsk thank you...which is the differents between
error and exception?

Comment: @Gelso77 Before php 7 you could not catch errors, they were always fatal. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.errors.php7.php for more information.